# Identify Rounded Modern Sans Serif

Tags: fonts, typography, font-identification

Can anyone ID this font? It is giving me fits even though I feel like its on the tip of my tongue:

[image: Northwest Logo]

I've tried both http://www.whatfontis.com and What the Font

Edit: this is from an HVAC Contractors website. They have a low resolution logo issued to me for some work they've asked me to do but cannot provide me a vector/high-res version so I must recreate it.

Here is the full logo:

[image]